# Bayesian ANOVA : simple main effect and post-hoc analysis

Tags: r, bayesian, anova, jasp

I'm conducting a two-way ANOVA with one within-subjects factor A (A1; A2) and one between-subjects factor B (B1; B2), but I would like conduct this with the bayesian approach. I did it with JASP.

However, is it possible to compute simple main effect for Bayesian ANOVA ? If yes, how can I do it ? This option is not available in JASP, thus can I do it with t-test, as it's possible in frequentist approach when interaction is significant ?
Or, is it possible to do it with R ?

Moreover, I computed bayesian post-hoc in JASP and BF were the same than Bayesian t-test... So I did not understand why...

Finally, my last question is about power. I don't have many participants, so how to know if my bayesian analysis did not suffer from a lack of power when BF shows anecdotical evidence ?

I have read this article on the topic but did not find an answer :

Jong, Marsman, Wagenmakers (2019)

Bergh, D. Van Den, Doorn, J. Van, Marsman, M., Draws, T., van Kesteren, E.-J., Derks, K., … Wagenmakers, E. J. (2019). A Tutorial on Conducting and Interpreting a Bayesian ANOVA in JASP. 1–22. doi:[10.31234/osf.io/spreb](https://doi.org/10.31234/osf.io/spreb)

Rouder, J. N., Engelhardt, C. R., McCabe, S., & Morey, R. D. (2016). Model comparison in ANOVA. Psychonomic Bulletin and Review, 23(6), 1779–1786. doi:[10.3758/s13423-016-1026-5](https://doi.org/10.3758/s13423-016-1026-5)

Thanks for your answer,

PM

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackexchange.

> However, is it possible to compute simple main effect for Bayesian ANOVA ? If yes, how can I do it ? This option is not available in JASP, thus can I do it with t-test, as it's possible in frequentist approach when interaction is significant ? Or, is it possible to do it with R ?
>
> Moreover, I computed bayesian post-hoc in JASP and BF were the same than Bayesian t-test... So I did not understand why...

The simple main effects in your design capture the difference between `A1` and  `A2`, or between `B1` and `B2`. These should already available in the ANOVA input of any program, including JASP.

> Finally, my last question is about power. I don't have many participants, so how to know if my bayesian analysis did not suffer from a lack of power when BF shows anecdotical evidence ?

Power is a [frequentist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_inference) concept, and does not play a role in Bayesian statistics. However, you can answer your question quite easily in Bayesian statistics: if the BF indicates only *anecdotal evidence* in either direction (in favour of the null hypothesis, or in favour of the alternative), this means you don't have enough data to be sure that there **is** an effect, and you don't have enough data to be sure that there **isn't** an effect.

Comment: Thank your for your answer ! 

OK for statistical power. 

However about simple main effect, my purpose is to assess effect of A (i.e., difference between A1 and A2) B1 and B2. 
Post-hoc allow to capture difference between A1 and A2, as well as B1 and B2. But it is an analysis of main effect. I would like analysis interaction effect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question in that case. Could you please try to explain what it is you actually want to calculate? The main effect? Simple effects (e.g. `A1.B1` - `A1.B2`)? Interactions?

Comment: I would like calculate bayesian simple effects.

Comment: Then use a (Bayesian) t-test to compare each pair of groups (e.g. `A1.B1` - `A1.B2`).

Comment: Great ! Are there conditions (e.g., minimal BF for interaction) or precautions (e.g., correction) to use multiple t-test in this case ?
I mean, if there are not conditions or precautions why use ANOVA and not directly use multiple t-test ?